# Send emails asynchronously with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, email, asynchronous, laravel-5

How could email be sent asynchronously or in a faster way?

I made an application with the basic method:

```
PHP artisan make: mail demo
```

Then the view

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.demo');
    }
```

#### Sending the mail

```
public function index()
    {
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        Mail::to($email)->send(new DemoMail());
        return view('home');
    }
```

How could I send emails faster?

Comment: You could use message queueing - either something like RabbitMQ or just implement your own simple one by inserting a mail job into a table, and then have another script running as a daemon to process the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Emails can be sent using Laravel's built in [queuing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#queueing-mail) methods:

```
public function index() {
    $email = Auth::user()->email;

    Mail::to($email)->queue(new DemoMail());

    return view('home');
}
```

In order for this to work, you have to [configure your queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues) first.

Once your queues have been setup, you just need to queues being processed by a background worker using:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

This allows your emails to be sent asynchronously without slowing down the page load times for your visitors.